# Laptop keyboard suddenly started acting weird

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, 20.04, lenovo, capslock

I am using a Lenovo ThinkPad E570 i3, with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (updated from previous version) and Windows 10 Pro Dual Boot.

I was reading a book on evince, and it was the only app running. The network was disconnected. All of a sudden the Caps Lock Indicator LED lights up on the keyboard, without me pressing any key. The laptop was on a desk, and hasn't had any physical damage done to it.

Left Shift hasn't been working, and even using Right Shift only capitalises a few letters. The numeric keypad isn't working, neither are the backspace and enter keys. The delete and arrow keys work sometimes.
Caps Lock is even worse. It turns on, but doesn't turn off. It doesn't capitalise, but sometimes acts like Shift.

This happens in Windows too, and uninstalling the device through device manager doesn't change anything.

I tried the On Screen Keyboard, and it does work sometimes, but other times is the same as the hard keyboard, which is even more troubling. USB keyboard works perfectly. Changing keyboard layouts doesn't seem to help.

When rebooting, the Caps Lock Indicator LED is on, which doesn't happen normally.

These errors also happen when using tty1 or tty2.

Finally, this has happened on this laptop before, and I was on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS then. Fortunately I still had the iso file then, and I didn't have any important files so I completely reinstalled the OS, which fixed the issue. But this time I have important files and notes, and I only have mobile data, so downloading an entire iso file isn't feasible, so I'd prefer if this could be fixed without some big downloads.

Comment: Having same problem on Windows and Ubuntu usually limits the problem to a hardware fault.  I think fault might be a loose connection to keyboard or maybe dirt build up inside of machine.  Can google your machine with repair keyboard to see how difficult.  Use USB board for now.

Comment: As I mentioned, I had this problem before, but it was fixed by reinstalling the OS completely, which I can't do this time. And it's worked for about two years without any issues since then. And, this also happens with the on screen keyboard.

Comment: If it happens in Windows and Ubuntu, it has to be a hardware fault.  If it only happens in one, then a software fault.  Hardware faults can be very weird if just partial.  Confirm if it happens in both or just one OS. Lenovo is usually good for Linux.

Comment: One thing you could try is seeing if bios version has an update available from Lenovo.  Usually nicer if done in windows.